# Convert 2e+08 to integer in Java

Tags: java, types, number-formatting

I'd like to know what the `2e+08` format in programming means? 
I have some data related to project budget. How to convert it into integer in Java ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`2e+08` means *2* multiplied by *10^8*. In other words, *2* followed by *8* zeros:

> 2e+08 = 200000000

To convert it to an `int` we can simply cast:

```
int n = (int)2e+08
```

---

All of the following are equivalent in Java: `2e+08`, `2e08`, `2e8`, `2E+08`, `2E08`, `2E8`.

Comment: It would probably be easier to avoid using any floating point at all and avoid the conversion

Comment: Well we don't know where the OP gets this value, maybe it is returned by some function in some library that uses floating-point.

Comment: What you have, and what OP has, is a literal. In which case, make it an `int` literal.

Comment: @SteveKuo Try the following: `System.out.println((1e2 + 1) / 2)` and `System.out.println((100 + 1) / 2)`. The first prints `50.5` (regular division) and the second prints `50` (integer division) - showing that `1e2` is not an integer (in the Java-sense) but rather a double. Same can be said for `2e+08`.

Answer (score 0):

That number uses [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation). The `e` signifies exponentiation, in this case to base 10. So this number is 2×10<sup>8</sup>.

Because calculators, computer programming languages etc. typically do not use superscript notation, `e` is used to indicate the exponentiation.

To represent that number in Java, as an integer literal, write it like this:

```
200000000
```

As @Saintali helpfully points out, in Java SE 7 and later you can use underscores in the literal to improve clarity:

```
200_000_000
```

If the data you are reading uses scientific notation, then it represents floating point values. Should you really be converting this to integer data? If you do need to read this in from file and then convert to int, you should read into a floating point data type and then cast to `int`.

Comment: Ints can hold up to 2147483647.